# Python re module findall and print the entire match substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a complex issue in python.

I would like to print match occurrence number and string in my console like here:https://regex101.com/r/yA4wS1/1

As you can see the online regex tester show the match highlighted so that you can see the entire match and its length.

I would like to do the same in my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\w)\1\1\1+', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u'aaaaaadgfdhgfbbbbgggee)ehje ekekkkkkeefh ehfeff88888éh\"hr ekkKKKKK\njhxjhjhhhhh\nthe the\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"aaaeeeeeeeeaaaadzxzzzzffffrrrr\"\n\"aaa\"'

#m = re.findall(p, test_str)
m = p.findall(test_str)

print (m)
```

but python juste print the list of groups (a list of one character size strings)

```
/home/nixmind/devspace/py_algo> ./str_count_match_re.py
[u'a', u'b', u'k', u'8', u'K', u'h', u'e', u'a', u'a', u'z', u'e', u'a', u'a', u'z', u'e', u'a', u'a', u'z', u'e', u'a', u'z', u'f', u'r']
```

What I would like is to print the entire match place (means all the consecutive characters sequence), and the lenght of the matched sub string.

Can someone help to get there with **re** module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns the captured submatches.

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, **as a list of strings***... If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

You can use [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) that allows easy access to all the matched groups including the 0th one (i.e. the whole match):

> Return an iterator yielding **MatchObject** instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string.

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\w)\1\1\1+')
test_str = u'aaaaaadgfdhgfbbbbgggee)ehje ekekkkkkeefh ehfeff88888éh\"hr ekkKKKKK\njhxjhjhhhhh\nthe the\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"eeeeeeeeaaaabcaaaaadexxxdddzdzzzz\"\n\"aaaeeeeeeeeaaaadzxzzzzffffrrrr\"\n\"aaa\"'
print ([x.group(0) for x in p.finditer(test_str)])
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/aFnePT)

Note that `re.MULTILINE` is redundant here, since you have no `^` nor `$` in the pattern to redefine the behavior of.

Comment: The crucial factor is that `finditer()` returns match objects (which have lots of information), not strings like `findall()`.

Comment: Yes I saw **finditer** but I wanted to write an optimized codet seems like it the only choice here. 
It works, I wile check the code execution time for each method.